# Undefined control sequence when macro defined using pgfkeys contains an ampersand

Tags: tables, pgfkeys

I'm currently figuring out how to use `pgfkeys`, and I'm running into the following problem. I'm trying to define a command that prints part of a table, filled with arguments provided through `pgfkeys`. A simplified version of my situation looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys,xparse}
\pgfkeys{
    /test/.is family, /test,
    right/.estore in=\testright,
    left/.estore in=\testleft,
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tablepart}{o}{
    \pgfkeys{/test,#1}
    \testleft{} & \testright{} \\
    \testleft{} & \testright{} \\
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \tablepart[left={ABC},right={DEF}]{}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However, this setup gives me an `Undefined control sequence` error on `\tablepart[left={ABC},right={DEF}]{}`. If I remove the ampersand and `\\` in the definition of `\tablerow`, however, the error disappears. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: a table cell is a group so all definitions reset at the &

Comment: Same problem: [Q649183](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/649183)
Related problem: [Q653795](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/653795)

Comment: Pull the `tabular` usage into your `\tablepart` macro so that you set the values outside of the `tabular` environment. That way, the will all be accessoble. What are you trying to achieve? `\NewDocumentCommand{\tablepart}{o}{\begingroup\pgfqkeys{/test}{#1}\begin{tabular}{rl}\testleft&\testright\\\testleft&\testright\\\end{tabular}\endgroup}`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirbel the idea is that I can use the macro to insert multiple similarly structured sections into the same table. I can see how your idea would work, but that would put everything in a separate table.

Comment: Then this approach: `\newcommand*\addtomacro[2]{\expandafter\def\expandafter#2\expandafter{#2#1}}\NewDocumentCommand{\tablepart}{o}{\pgfqkeys{/test}{#1}\def\mymacro{}\expandafter\addtomacro\expandafter{\testleft&}{\mymacro}\expandafter\addtomacro\expandafter{\testright\\}{\mymacro}\mymacro}` You basically build the row and put it (including `&` and `\\`) in a macro and use it at the end. Though, I feel there are so many table package for LaTeX that there might be already a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a table cell is a group so all definitions reset at the `&`

However you can expand the command while still in the first cell.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys,xparse}
\newcommand\hmm{&}

\pgfkeys{
    /test/.is family, /test,
    right/.estore in=\testright,
    left/.estore in=\testleft,
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tablerow}{o}{
    \pgfkeys{/test,#1}
    \testleft{} \expandafter\hmm\testright{} \\
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \tablerow[left={ABC},right={DEF}]{}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Or for the version added later (`\ExpandArgs` predfined in 2022 LaTX but it could be defined for older releases)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys,xparse}
\def\hmm#1#2{#1&#2\\#1&#2\\}

\pgfkeys{
    /test/.is family, /test,
    right/.estore in=\testright,
    left/.estore in=\testleft,
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tablepart}{o}{
    \pgfkeys{/test,#1}
     \ExpandArgs{oo}\hmm{\testleft}{\testright}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \tablepart[left={ABC},right={DEF}]{}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this does indeed solve the problem in the example I posted! Unfortunately it turns out I simplified the example too much: the real version of my `\tablerow` contains multiple table rows. I tried doing the same thing with the `\\` as you show here with the `&`, but that does still give the error. I've updated the question with a more accurate example.

Comment: @JordiVermeulen same basic idea, I added a working version

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to make this work on a per-row basis? I'm trying to make some sort of template for a repeating part of a table that gets its data filled using the macro with pgfkeys. I can ask a new question if that's too far removed from my original question.

Comment: @JordiVermeulen new q I think (with new example)

Comment: I asked a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/654604/278532. I've accepted this answer, as it does answer the question as stated here.